# Redshift : Invalid operation: Maximum number of stored procedures allowed exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to create this procedure in redshift

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Test_max_proc()
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$          

DECLARE 

        v_DATE_MAX          DATE;
        v_DATE_MIN            DATE;
        v_FILE_TYPE            VARCHAR(3);

        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
                RAISE NOTICE 'STEP: % ERROR = %',v_STEP_NM, v_PROC_MESSAGE ;

                RAISE NOTICE 'PROC: % TOT FAILED ROW COUNT: %', v_PROC_NM, v_TOT_ROW_CNT;


                RAISE NOTICE 'ERR AT STEP: % - % DDL = % Timestamp: %',v_STEP_SEQ, v_STEP_NM, v_STEP_DDL,v_STEP_START_TIME;
                RAISE NOTICE 'ERROR: %',SQLERRM ;            
                ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    END;
      $$
;
```

~
But I am getting error saying Invalid operation: Maximum number of stored procedures allowed exceeded.

I can not find any documentation for this.

Is there any limit in redshift for maximum no of procedure.

Comment: ideally you should ask AWS support for help on this.

Comment: I have emailed them but no response and it is kind of critical for me,if you can help.

Comment: how many do you have already? can you edit the question so that the code inside the code block is syntactically correct (i.e. would run if i was to copy paste it in to redshift)

Comment: I have edited the question, I have 1014 stored procedures in my database.

Comment: OK - i guess the limit is undocumented at 1024 - you need to contact aws support.

Comment: Thanks Jon, Got the same reply that limit per database is 1024 and can be increased.